# Why doesn't our chat have easter eggs

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Iv'e seen Root Access'es Clippy egg...

I have seen Arquade minigame egg...

I have also seen rm -rf / on Serverfault chat...

BUT WHAT I HAVENT SEEN IS...

ASKUBUNTU EGGS.

Why can't we have a unique egg implented into our chat that (i know this is abusive) can be funny, or pranky....

Comment: Maybe something useful like Reddit's [/u/CompileBot](https://www.reddit.com/r/CompileBot/wiki/index)?

Comment: I did not hear of easter eggs in SE chat yet, can you explain them to me please?

Comment: @bytecommander Try this egg: In root access, type I want clippy to appear

Comment: woops try I want to punch a wall